# GIT Trace when using Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

is there a way to specify GIT_TRACE=1 when using git within Xcode?

IE if I am trying to clone, pull, push, etc a git project with Xcode IDE can I enable GIT_TRACE (or other GIT environment variables)? If so where would the output go?

I am using latest Xcode (12.4).

Comment: Git should work independent to Xcode within your shell. You can then use it's interface as advertised in the Git manual. The implementation and interface within an IDE can greatly differ (and then has different debugging / logging options). This is normally outlined in the documentation of the IDE.

Comment: Yes, it does work in shell; and in shell it works as expected so need to know how to use the trace in Xcode. It worked fine up until v12 of Xcode and now has some problems that I am trying to debug.

Comment: Sounds like a typical support question. Address it to Xcode, they should be able to answer it.

Comment: you would think so but the specific problem was first reported as a bug to Apple during the beta releases of Xcode 12 and has persisted in all of the released versions. There has been no official response from Xcode support. So it needs to be debugged at the Xcode level and I am just trying to find out if anyone knows how to enable GIT TRACE within Xcode IDE.

Comment: Export the variable and then start Xcode from shell. Maybe that works.